# Cant connect to server when using Socket.io and React

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I am attempting to use socket.io with React. I've followed the template provided on socket.io
however I am confused on how to actually have my socket connect.

Currently my socket.js file is :

```
\`import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

const URL = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? undefined : 'http://localhost:3000';

export const socket = io(URL);\`
```

and my app.js file is like :

```
\`

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { socket } from './socket';

export default function App() {
const \[isConnected, setIsConnected\] = useState(socket.connected);
const \[fooEvents, setFooEvents\] = useState(\[\]);

useEffect(() =\> {
function onConnect() {
setIsConnected(true);
}

    socket.on('connect', onConnect);
    
    
    return () => {
      socket.off('connect', onConnect);
      
    };

}, \[\]);

return (
\<div className="App"\>

    </div>

);
}\`
```

when I console.log socket or socket.connect im seeing that there is no connection happening. Im not sure if im possibly missing a 'listen' somewhere but not entirely sure where that would go exactly. Any help or push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried rewriting this following this tutorial https://deepinder.me/creating-a-real-time-chat-application-with-react-hooks-socket-io-and-nodejs

However I still have the same issue of no connection occurring. I have install my dependencies (express, node, socket.io , socket.io-client) and run node socket.js to begin listening, however nothing else is happening.

Comment: Also share your node js code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a node server with this code. this should listen for a socket connection and log it if something comes through.

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http, {
  cors: {
    origins: ['http://localhost:3000']
  }
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('<h1>Hey Socket.io</h1>');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});

http.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```